# Duplicate data displayed from previous firestore database fetches

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

I am new to coding in dart, and I was trying to build a basic app with a firebase baackend for authentication and firestore for CRUD functionalities. The authentication and creation of new user is a success, but on trying to read from the firestore database using FutureBuilder, there is a problem I am facing.The Home page of the app (which is the page the control flows to once authentications is successful) does not display the contents on the first launch of the app, if I just re-save, the auto reload function which is enabled rebuilds the app to display the contents fetched from firestore. But on subsequent re-saves the screen is poplulated with duplicates of the same contents. As in the page is not refreshed to display the content once, rather the summation of contents from all calls until said call is displayed at once in the Home page. I have added the code snippets below.

The Home page file

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_project_1/screens/home/read_data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  // The list of all document IDs,
  //which have access to each their own personal information
  List<String> documentIDs = [];

  // DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>(Users/8bu245T440NIuQnJhm81)
  // This is the sample output, to get IDs we just do .id
  Future getDocIDs() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').get().then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
            // for(document in snapshot.docs)
            (document) {
              {
                print(document.reference);
                documentIDs.add(document.reference.id);
              }
              ;
            },
          ),
        );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getDocIDs();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            'Display dashboard',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              color: Colors.tealAccent.shade400,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
            },
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.logout_sharp,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple.shade200,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // This has a FutureBuilder as it needs
            // to wait for executiion of getDocIDs function to finish execution
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder<Object>(
                builder: (context, index) {
                  future:
                  getDocIDs();
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: documentIDs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: ReadData(docIDs: documentIDs[index]),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the file with the read data function to display info on screen

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReadData extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReadData({required this.docIDs, super.key});

  final String docIDs;

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    // get the collection
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(docIDs).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        //IF connection with the firebase is ensured, then we execute
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          //We are trying to map the key and values pairs 
          //to a variable called "data" of Type Map
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          //Returning the value for key called name
          return Text('name: ${data['name']}');
        }
        return const Text('Loading......');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `getDocIDs()` twice: once in `initState` and once inside the `FutureBuilder` in the `build` method. Since you never clear the `documentIDs` list, you end up with each document ID in there twice.

The simplest way to fix this, is to call `setState` in `getDocIDs` to signal to Flutter that it needs to repaint the UI:

```
void getDocIDs() {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
        print(document.reference);
        documentIDs.add(document.reference.id);
      })
      setState(() {}); 
    });
  );
}
```

And then get rid of the `FutureBuilder` in your `build` method, as it's no longer needed once you call `setState`:

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: documentIDs.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(
        title: ReadData(docIDs: documentIDs[index]),
      );
    },
  )
);
```

Comment: Just a small tweak, I made the function a Future and added the async keyword, then used await before it could fetch from firebase. And it works!! The original suggestion did not display any result for some reason, but from that i was able to figure it out, THANKS A TON!!!!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. I noticed that I had the call to `setState` in the wrong spot, which explains why the UI didn't update after loading the data. I fixed that in the code in my answer now.